# Republishing artifacts / JAR with version update

Tags: github, jenkins, version-control, artifacts

I created a new repo from scratch. About 50 pull requests have been merged. One thing I forgot to add is automatic version update which will work for only newly added pulls. I am looking for a mechanism where a new commit (version change) can be added between two commits and generate artifacts again.

e.g.
Master: A -> B -> C -> D -> E and so on.

With new version changes master will finally look like

With Versions: A -> V1 -> B -> V2 -> C -> V3 -> D -> V4 -> E -> V5

Also Jenkins JAR artifacts should generate like below:

- Run 1: A -> V1
- Run 2: A -> V1 -> B -> V2
- Run 3: A -> V1 -> B -> V2 -> C -> V3
- Run 4: A -> V1 -> B -> V2 -> C -> V3 -> D -> V4
- Run 5: A -> V1 -> B -> V2 -> C -> V3 -> D -> V4 -> E -> V5

and so on....

Would appreciate help. Thanks !